# Machine translation fails with: The file could not be downloaded from the SharePoint library because the user's permissions have changed

Tags: variations, machine-translation

My Environment is SharePoint 2013 on a Windows Server 2012 with Variations set-up.

When trying to use the button in the ribbon called Machine translate the job gets in the que but fails with the error message:

> The file could not be downloaded from the SharePoint library because
>   the user's permissions have changed.